# DML takes long time on custom object with no triggers/WF/PB on it

Tags: dml, dml-operations

I've got a code, where on lead insert, I also insert 1 record of custom object Demand_Funnel__c. Demand_Funnel__c has no apex triggers, no WF rules, no Processes tied on it. If it's a first lead insertion of the day, Demand_Funnel__c insertion could take up to 6 seconds.

[image: Developer console timeline]
[image: Logs]
[image: Debug log levels]

All subsequent insertions take 0.1-0.2 secs.

Additional info about enviroment/object:
Object has ~1.5 million of records. Object has 260 custom fields and 12 custom relationship fields. Org itself has tens of millions of records.

I've only found [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fz3cIAA) with similar issue with no answer.

Does anybody know, why simple insertion can take up to 6 seconds on first insertion of the day?

Comment: Salesforce warms up their cache. Can you check what is happening when you open random record 2 years past on object with coupe millions of records? (spoiler alert -- I have seen environments when it took up to 4 times timeout (120 sec) till record is shown)

Comment: @kurunve opened a Demand_Funnel__c record for 2013, opened in a second. Tried to open an old lead, open time was usual 2-3 seconds.